# Secure communication between existing Azure App Service and Azure VM cluster

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

We have an application running in Azure that consists of the following:

1. A Web App front end, which talks to…
2. A WebApi running as a Web App as well, which can (as well as a couple other services) talk to…
3. A Cloud Service load balanced set of VMs which Are hosting an Elasticsearch cluster.

*Additionally we have the scenario were dev’s whitelist their IPs so that their localhost version of the API can hit the VMs as well.*

We have locked down our Elasticsearch VM’s by adding ACLs to the exposed end point.  I whitelisted the outbound IPs that were listed on my App Services.  I was under the mistaken impression that these were unique to my Api.  It turns out that these are shared across the scale unit in Azure.  Other services running in the same scale unit, could, if they knew the endpoint, access the data exposed on the endpoint in my cluster.  I need to lock this down, and I am trying to find the easiest way.  These are the things I am looking at, and I would appreciate advice and/or redirection.

- Elastic Shield: Not being considered.  This is a product by Elastic
  that is designed to secure ES.  This is ideal, but at the moment it
  is out of scope (due to the cost and overhead)
- List item
- Elastic plugins: Not being considered.   The main plugins (such as
  Jetty) appear to be abandoned.
- Azure VPN.  I originally tried to set this up, but ran into too many
  difficulties.  The ACLs seemed to give me what I need without much
  difficulty.  I am not sure if I can set this up now. The things I
  don’t know are:

  1. I don’t think I can move existing VMs into a new VPN.
  2. I think you have to recreate the VMs in that VPN from the get go
     Could I move my    Web App into the VPN?  How does that work?
  3. This would prob break my developer scenario as the localhost API
     would not be able to access the VPN, right?
- Add a certificate to requests: It would be ideal if I could have
  requests require a cert or a header token.  I assume to do this I
  would need to create a proxy that would run on the VMs and do the
  validation before forwarding the request on to my Elasticsearch.
- Anything else?  Is there another option I have not thought of?

Thanks!
~john

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VPN point-to-site connecting your Web App with your IaaS VMs. This is the best solution because you will be able to use just internal IPs on your IaaS.

The easiest way to do that using Azure Portal is create a Web App and, create a new VPN and VNet using "setup" option at "Your Web App" -> Settings -> Networking -> VNET Integration -> Setup -> Create New Virtual Network.

After that, create your IaaS inside this new VNet.

You also can create a ARM template to create Web App, IaaS, VPN and everything that you need. Take a look at my ARM template to create PHP+MySQL using Web App and MariaDB Cluster connected by VPN: https://github.com/juliosene/azure-webapp-php-mariadb

Comment: Thanks Julio.  I assume, however that I A) can't move my existing VMs (which are currently serving content to our customers) into this new VPN, and B) I would not be able to access the VMs from our on premise localhost/debug version of our Web App.  Is that correct?

Comment: Jonh,
A) If your VMs are running, the better way to connect to a Web App is creating an point-to-site VPN based on your existing VNets.
You can follow this guide to do that: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/

B) If you need to connect your on prime  Web App to Azure IaaS, you can also create a point-to-site VPN or a site-to-site VPN (depends on your scenario). The best movement is move your develop/test environment to the Azure Cloud. It's gonna be more easy to manage.